# How best to add UNC file paths to a Java Classpath

Tags: java, classpath, unc

Using Java (1.4) is there a way in which to use Windows UNC file locations (\\servername\filestore\etc) within the classpath?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you just need to swap the back slashes with forward slashes:

```
java -classpath '//servername/filestore/etc;.' <classname>
```