# How to Read file from a shared location Windows? (Java)

Tags: java, file

Is there a way to read a file from a network shared location on windows?

Let's say for instance I've this simple code that reads a text file called ***readMe.txt*** from the ***Addons*** folder.

```
import java.io.File;

class Sample{

    public static void main(String[] ar){
        File file = new File("Addons/ReadMe.txt");
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
      //followed by printing the contents of file   
    }
}
```

And I execute this file using a windows batch ***runme.bat*** that has

```
java Sample
PAUSE
```

The bat runs and executes the above class only when I place the Addons folder with ReadMe.txt, Sample.class, runme.bat file in my local drive.

When it is placed in a network shared location with UNC path like ***\\name\Shared***

In such a scenario, the bat file typically starts the base from ***C:\Windows*** and throws a classNotFoundException. I can rather map the shared drive to a ***Z:*** drive or whatever but I do not want to do it.

I want the code to programatically detect and retrieve the content of Readme.txt in Addons folder irrespective of whether it is being executed on a local drive or on a shared drive. Is there a way to achieve this? Please help..

> Thanks
>
> Veekay

Comment: You might find a hint here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682194/java-read-file-from-network-device

Comment: Not as far as I know. Mapped drive yes but UNC path no.

Comment: Also, this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825731/how-best-to-add-unc-file-paths-to-a-java-classpath

Comment: How ever there is a DLL on free which you can use with java and access UNC but not straight away but I am not 100% hence only leaving as comment. 100%DLL way but not 100% with out it . If I am making any sense.

Comment: If you are getting a class not found exception it means you haven't got your environment setup correctly. i.e. it hasn't even tried to use your UNC path as it couldn't load the class.

Comment: try '//' instead of '\\'

Comment: I am sure the classNotFoundException is not because of the environment set up. It has got to do with the way windows batch works. When we run a batch file from a shared location that is not mapped, it defaults to C:\Windows which obviously doesn't have the classes and hence the classNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing.

1) Map the shared path to a local drive.

2) Else hard code the server path in new File('') as mentioned by Medopal.

Something like `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` might help me get the base Folder when executed on a local system. Likewise there is no such way to programmatically find out the working base when executed on a shared location.

Answer (score 7):

When using a file path in Java, make sure to escape all `\` correctly when giving the full path name.

For example, if the file is on PC with IP `(10.10.10.123)` on a Shared folder called `Addons` then the full path will be:

```
File f = new File ("\\\\10.10.10.123\\Addons\\readme.txt");
```

Other than the full path, your code is throwing a `ClassNotFound` because you JAVA-CLASSPATH is not set properly.

Comment: Thanks but I want it to be able to run on any shared location without the necessity to hardcode the baseFolder.

Comment: What to do if the shared path was protected with password?

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR did you get your answer ? I had the same query

Answer (score 1):

In your bat file `%~dp0` expands to the location of the bat file. You need that in your classpath so that java can find the class, though I don't know if it will choke on UNC path. For example:

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0
```

would output

```
\\host\share\dir
```

EDIT: %dp0 will not work if there are spaces. This is what you need in your bat file:

```
@echo off
set p=%~dps0
echo %p%
java -classpath %p%\jarname classname
pause
```