# Read files from other systems

Tags: java

How to retrieve file details like name, modification date, absolute path etc., of another system in same network?
I am using like this

File f = new File("//192.168.3.142/E:");

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you cannot do this.  You can't access arbitrary file details from another system.

However, on an appropriately configured Windows system, you *can* refer to network shares on remote systems.  See this Q&A for details:  [How to Read file from a shared location Windows? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481200/how-to-read-file-from-a-shared-location-windows-java)

Similarly, on Linux or other Unix-like operating systems, you can access remote file systems that have been mounted; e.g. via NFS.