# How to get access to document in tomcat server side

Tags: java, tomcat

In my project, I have a .pdf,.docx,etc. documents in my tomcat server side. I want to access them and I want to copy them in my local computer drive. But I get this error every time.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\ptrisf02\group2\Engine_Follow\V2500-A5\V2500-A5_e-Archive\EV11929-02\MiniPack\GEN\EV11929-02 ACCESSORY AND EBU CHECK LIST EEV. 01.pdf (Access is denied)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.solr.openDocumentServlet.doPost(openDocumentServlet.java:78)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I tried to change `catalina.policy` to give permissions. But it didn't work. How can I solve this problem?? This is the code snippet that I added to `catalina.policy`.

```
//These permissions apply to the E-Archive
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/E-Archive"{
        permission java.io.FilePermission
          "${\\\\ptrisf02\\group2\\Engine_Follow}","read";
};
```

My codes like this

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Docpath=request.getParameter("document");
        String docname=request.getParameter("docName");
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out);
        pw.write(Docpath);
        String r_Docpath=Docpath.replace("\"", "\\");
        String r2_Docpath=r_Docpath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        //response.getWriter().append(r2_Docpath);
        File original=new File(r2_Docpath);
        File destination=new File("D:\\");


        try {
            //Files.copy(original.toPath(), destination.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(original, destination);

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File file=new File("D:\\"+docname);
        Path filePath=Paths.get("D:\\"+docname);
        response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(filePath));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+docname);

        InputStream input=new FileInputStream(Docpath);

        //FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(Docpath);

        ServletOutputStream  outs =  response.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(input);
        BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(outs);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096]; 
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buf)) > 0) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);

        }
        bis.close();
        bos.close();


        //doGet(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: First check if the file exists. Second, check if the user who has started the tomcat has permission to read the file in file system. Also, what is the HTTP error you are getting. Please post the mechanism (code etc.) how you are trying to access the file.

Comment: @Ironluca I'm getting HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error and I add my codes in my post.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the use of the following line: 
String r_Docpath=Docpath.replace("\"", "\\");
String r2_Docpath=r_Docpath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
How does the input string looks and what is the intended output of the operations

Comment: My input string like this `\\ptrisf02\group2\Engine_Follow\V2500-A5\V2500-A5_e-Archive\EV11929-02\MiniPack\GEN\EV11929-02 AFTER TEST BSI.pdf`. This file in my network location, I want to copy it my local drive D:\ and I want to open copied file. I able to open the file using windows run command but when I want to access file using my project, it gives me this error.I made this codes `String r Docpath=Docpath.replace("\"", "\\"); String r2 Docpath=r Docpath.replace("\\", "\\\\"); `  because I thought maybe the file path has error.

Comment: 1) try mapping the folder to a local drive
2) use fully qualified win path '\\<IP>\folder\fileName', refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481200/how-to-read-file-from-a-shared-location-windows-java

Comment: @Ironluca OK. I'll try it.