# How to access files from shared location using java 8 or any recent ways to access using java?

Tags: java, file, shared-memory, remote-access, remote-server

I have found how to access but these links are old, one of the link is

[How to Read file from a shared location Windows? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481200/how-to-read-file-from-a-shared-location-windows-java)

All I want is some recent way to do it if possible.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question to show us what actual problem you are facing. It is also a good idea to show the code you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy by using new nio2 package, i.e. Path

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/test/resources/fileTest.txt"); 
String read = Files.readAllLines(path).get(0);
```

Of coz you can retrieve file name, path, location by its API. hope it solved your problem

Comment: I think this is the way to read the files if files are their in our system, but I was asking how to access files from a shared location.

Comment: @Anubhav if it is a mount drive location, replace the path url with server ip and directory should be fine. if the drive is an FTP etc, it cannot be achieved using this way, but if it is a FTP server or with protocol, please use FTPClient and etc to do so.